# composer always detect wrong version of my local php

Tags: php, macos, terminal

Whenever I try to test PHPUnit or composer update, I get this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 7.4.0". You are running 7.3.19
```

but when I put on the terminal: `source ~/.bash_profile` it reads that I have 7.4 on my local machine and all works OK. Is there any solution for that issue, to not need to put every time that command `source ~/.bash_profile` before every start of the console?

Before run `source ~/.bash_profile`:

```
PHP 7.3.19 (cli) (built: Jun 12 2020 00:29:59) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.19, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.3.19, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

After run `source ~/.bash_profile`:

```
PHP 7.4.13 (cli) (built: Nov 30 2020 14:57:43) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.4.13, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

Comment: What do you mean by _"when I put on the terminal: source ~/.bash_profile it reads that I have 7.4"_? Did you do a `php -v` in your terminal to check what version it actually uses?

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson take a look update

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, I was using command prompt for laravel artisan commands. Which was showing wrong php version. I closed it and from Xampp Control Pannel Open the Shell for artisan commands and now its detecting the correct PHP Version. It fixed my problem.